# Rename last index of pandas dataframe and coerce dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a doubt. I have a dataframe df and I need to change the index of the last row, this is probably easy but I'm having troubles doing it:

```
              A    B
2017-02-09   2.4  3.4
2017-02-10   3.4  3.2 
2017-02-13   3.3  2.2
0            3.1  2.1
```

I need to change that "0" index at the last row with today's date 2017-02-14, how can I do this ?

I have tried:

```
df.set_index[len(df)-1](dt.date.today())
```

where dt stands for datetime. It does not work, any idea ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`DF.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a `dict` mapping to change the labels along the index axis as shown:

```
import datetime

df.rename({df.index[-1]: datetime.date.today()}, inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)   # Convert dtype to DateTimeIndex
```

[image]

Check the `dtypes`:

```
df.index.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

***Note:*** You cannot use `set_index[..]` as these refer to the built-in methods that aren't subscriptable. Instead, you must use it like `set_index(..)` with enclosed parentheses.

---

A succinct manner to coerce the `dtypes` in one-line by converting the index to it's series representation and [`replacing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) just the last value with today's date:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.to_series().replace({df.index[-1]:datetime.date.today()}))
```

gives:

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2017-02-09', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much, I was really stuck on it

Answer (score 0):

```py
ind = df.index.tolist()
ind[len(ind)-1] = dt.date.today()
df.index = ind
```